# C# - What's the fastest way to convert a number to the smallest BitArray

Tags: c#

I would like to convert a number to a BitArray, with the resulting BitArray only being as big as it needs to be.

For instance:

```
BitArray tooBig = new BitArray(new int[] { 9 });
```

results in a BitArray with a length of 32 bit, however for the value 9 only 4 bits are required. How can I create BitArrays which are only as long as they need to be? So in this example, 4 bits. Or for the number 260 I expected the BitArray to be 9 bits long

Comment: FWIW, I don't think that is supported. Documentation suggests that `BitArray` is mostly for when you need to store > 32 bits. `BitVector32` is supposedly faster, but as the name implies, it has a fixed size.

Comment: `BitArray` [uses an `int[]`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/bitarray.cs,520) under the hood, so if you are looking for a performance gain you aren't going to get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can figure out all the bits first and then create the array by checking if the least significant bit is 1 or 0 and then right shifting until the number is 0.  Note this will not work for negative numbers where the 32nd bit would be 1 to indicate the sign.

```
public BitArray ToShortestBitArray(int x)
{
    var bits = new List<bool>();
    while(x > 0)
    {
        bits.Add((x & 1) == 1);
        x >>= 1;
    }
    
    return new BitArray(bits.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working with exclusively unsigned integers, the number of bits you need is equal to the base 2 logarithm of the (number+1), rounded up.

Comment: While that’s useful information, it doesn’t answer the question about how to handle the conversion. Can you edit your answer to include e.g. code that demonstrates how to put this information into practice?

Answer (score 0):

Counting the bits is probably the easiest solution.

In JavaScript for example...

```
// count bits needed to store a positive number
const bits = (x, b = 0) => x > 0 ? bits(x >> 1, b + 1) : b;
```